# Decoding custom base64 image

Tags: javascript, base64, decoding

I'm trying to decode a custom base64 image in my web application but for some reason I'm facing some difficulties.
The server returns an image as custom base64 string:

```
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
```

I do also get information about width, height, bytesize & and format. The format in this case is "Mono 8 bit".

Is there anyway that this string can be decoded to the image?

**Edit #1**

Here is a simple code. Iam just trying to append it to the src of the element. Like this, which of course wont work:

```
const imgData = "base64 string from above";
const image = document.getElementById('testImage');
image.src = "data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64, + " imgData;
```

Comment: What's your currently used code?

Comment: @PatricNox I have added some simple code

Comment: You said the format is Mono 8 bit, well that's not a JPEG.

Comment: The encoded value from the backend seems to have gone wrong, just as Keith states above that is not a valid encoding for JPEG.

Comment: @Keith Yes and thats why I mentioned it wont work. The format is mono 8 bit.